# Multi-table Update in Oracle

Tags: multi-table

Just like Multi-table insert(using INSERT ALL) is there multi-table Update facility in Oracle? In which version?

Comment: You want to update multiple tables with one statement OR within one transaction ?

Comment: Yes, a single sql should be able to update multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is [no such facility in Oracle](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html) - you can't `UPDATE` multiple tables within one statement - you can use mutiple tables within an `UPDATE` statement but only one table can be updated.

What you could do is either wrap multiple `UPDATE` statements into one transaction and/or use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger which in turn contains multiple `UPDATE` statements...